# Defining a notion of extrinsic torsion

Tags: differential-geometry

We're familiar with the distinction between the intrinsic versus extrinsic curvature of a manifold. Like curvature, the intrinsic torsion of a manifold with connection is also perfectly well-defined, as:
$$T(X,Y) := \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X - [X,Y].$$
My question is: can one make quantitative a notion of the extrinsic torsion of a(n embedded) manifold, in analogy with extrinsic curvature? If so, how might this be done?